# rxbag plot does not show any message fields

Tags: ros, kinect, depth-image, rxbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the "plot" plugin for rxbag in order to plot (x,y,z) depth data from a kinect.  I'm able to open the plot gui, but when I click on the cog icon to select fields to plot, nothing happens.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Thanks,
Paul.

EDIT:  I am using electric on ubuntu 10.4.

EDIT:  rosbag info below...

```
$: rosbag info 2011-11-06-15-27-59.bag 
path:        2011-11-06-15-27-59.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    15.2s
start:       Nov 06 2011 15:28:01.39 (1320611281.39)
end:         Nov 06 2011 15:28:16.60 (1320611296.60)
size:        1.8 MB
messages:    452
compression: none [2/2 chunks]
types:       body_msgs/Skeletons [8d6667331403917cc53d8d820001e6f9]
topics:      /skeletons   452 msgs    : body_msgs/Skeletons (452 connections)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11818/rxbag-plot-does-not-show-any-message-fields/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-11-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-11-07**:
Pre-formatted text lines start with four spaces.

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-11-07**:
joq:  Apologies for another basic question:  How did you format the above edit to appear as it did on my screen?  (assuming you did this).

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-11-07**:
joq:  See my edit above regarding rosbag output.  Thanks.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-11-07**:
What does rosbag info say about this bag file?

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-11-06**:
Eric:  I am using electric on ubuntu 10.4.  I do not get any error messages in the terminal.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-11-06**:
Could you update your question to include which ROS release you are using (Diamondback, Electric, etc)? Do you get any error messages in the terminal where rxbag was run from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see anything wrong with your bag contents. It has data, apparently the right type.

Sometimes I've noticed `rxbag` refusing to display message contents if its cursor is positioned at the beginning of the data.

Try moving the cursor past the first few messages before attempting to plot.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-11-08**:
Agreed.  I'll check to see if one exists or open one.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-11-08**:
We should open a defect ticket for this problem. It's been happening for several releases.

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-11-07**:
Many thanks joq.  Moving the cursor did the trick.